# SSIS Send Mail Task Failed

Tags: ssis

The following is the error i get when i execute a simple package containing send mail task. i have configured the SMTP connection manager with server-smtp.office365.com and checked the windows authentication and ssl options too.

Thanks

> Error: 0xC002F304 at Send Mail Task, Send Mail Task: An error occurred
>   with the following error message: "**The SMTP server requires a secure
>   connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response
>   was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail
>   during MAIL FROM [BMXPR01CA0031.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]**".

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue. Check out [this msdn link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1d527cab-370b-4cb2-a0eb-3d754f23a39e/ssis-email-task-office-365?forum=sqlintegrationservices). It states the following in answer:

> The SMTP Task in SSIS **only supports Windows Authentication** and the
>   port number cannot be changed. For a SMTP server that uses non-Windows
>   Authentication, we can use SmtpClient Class in Script Task to send the
>   email

That's why sending email via office365 fails.

In order to work with office365, either you can look for third party plugins integration with SSIS or you can use `script task` like below:

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
.
.
.
public void Main()
{
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("<from email address>", "<to email address>");
 mail.Body = "ssis sample email body";
 mail.Subject = "ssis sample email subject";

 //mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(AttachmentDiscardContratti));
 //mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(AttachmentDiscardOrdini));

   SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587);
   client.EnableSsl = true;
   client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
   client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("<login email>", "<login password>");
   client.Send(mail);

   Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

ps: swap  and  as I am not sure which one comes first.

another sample of code is available [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962784/using-mailmessage-to-send-emails-in-c-sharp) (not tested by me)

Answer (score 1):

this can easly be achieved using execute sql task. first create a stored procedure and execute sp_send_dbmail in your newly created procedure. this sp requires many parameters .. pass the values of these parameters from ssis and u will be good. please search more on google about this procedure . u can even send attachments on this procedure